# Consistent CSS img transition on hover and click mobile and desktop

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, transform

I have an `img` with an `a href` around it, that when I hover it with my mouse it moves and scales (`transition` / `transform`). When I click it brings me too the destination of the `a href`. So far, so good.

However on mobile devices I can not hover it, it is only a click, so there is a short transition and then a redirect to the destination of the `a href`.

What would I expect/want?  On the desktop, keep it like it is. On mobile,
first click, apply the transform. Second click, redirect to the destination of the `a href`. how can I achieve this?

```css
/* IMAGE STYLES */

.banner_img_a img {
  position: relative;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 3px #000000);
  z-index: 100;
  transform: scale(1) rotate(20deg);
  transition: .3s opacity ease, .3s transform ease;
}


/* IMAGE STYLES HOVER*/

.banner_img_a img:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2000;
  transform: scale(2) rotate(0deg)translate(20px, 20px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="banner_img_a">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/ZRQFt9Yc/google.jpg" width="79" height="51">
</a>
```

Comment: Instead of forcing the mobile users to tap twice, which is really annoying behaviour for an animation which is entirely superfluous, I'd instead suggest you avoid the problem by having the element display in its final 'animated' position on mobile, and just have the single tap to follow the link.

Comment: Adding on to what Rory said you could detect if the user is on touchscreen by using `@media (hover: none)` which is better than assuming that all Android devices are touchscreen and all windows devices are not touchscreen. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan and Nate, thanks thats a better solutions than focusing on hover. 
wil make a solution without hover.

Answer (score 0):

You should not build your mobile UI with `hover` in mind. It just doesn't exist and normally leads to bad UX if forced on the user, as stated in the comments. But here are some alternatives I found by googling: https://uxpickle.com/alternatives-to-hover-interaction-on-touchscreens/